# Problem in Multiwrite Rule

Tags: mod-rewrite

U have used rewrite url module but not able to redirect to the target page and I am getting error as *The requested URL `/old.html` was not found on this server.*

Here is my code. Please see to that and suggest to me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/IN/$1 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^new.html$ /index.html$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule will probably cause an infinite rule as the substitute URL doesn’t use the port 8080 neither. So try this:

```
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/IN/$1 [L,R]
```

You also need to request `/new.html` to see if your second rule works. Additionally, there is no first group in your pattern whose match can be referenced by `$1`. So:

```
RewriteRule ^new\.html$ /index.html [L]
```